# Captured Image & show it next page in Silverlight asp.net

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have an Web-application in which I capture Image using EdgeCamShots Sample Application

[Saving Silverlight 4 Webcam](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/edgecam-shots-saving)

how can I use this capture image to be used in Next Page without saving Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view model object reference (created from the application's MainPage) would be an object that both pages would have access to.  Pass a reference to the pages on navigation changed event.    That view model might make a good container for the stream and would give both pages access to the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I don't have much Idea about MVVM Model ...can u guide me through any sample application to the point you want to convey..

Comment: Hi, Shaan  - That's a really broad topic, so I went to Google and did this search:  "mvvm silverlight open source tutorial application"  Then picked a few links from it, maybe they'll help:  http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/http://riba.codeplex.com/releases/view/60720  http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/the-mvvm-pattern/using-the-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-applications

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the stream (mentioned in the code example on the link you provided) to the next page using REST (adding the variable in the URL e.g. http://mysite/page2.aspx?stream=dstStream).
From there on, you can use the variable to show your picture.

Comment: I don't think that would work very well.  I didn't look at the link to see if it's encoded to convert binary to text, but if all is text - the querystring length limitations would not allow a very large image to be sent.

Comment: Is there any other way to do that..??

Comment: why do you want to avoid saving the image?

Comment: In my Web App , I need to Capture a person's Photo and pass that photo to Next Page where other fields related to the Person's info like Name Address etc are to be Input... You can assume the functionality similar to Facebook.. where a person can Capture his photo and Edit his details on Next page(tab)..

Comment: I still don't see why you couldn't save the captured image to the local file system and use it in the next page. I'm thinking temp folder or the likes.